# How to include a command at the start of every before_script in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
.debug: &debug
  - echo "$CI_PROJECT_NAME"
  - echo "$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE"
  - echo "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH"
  - echo "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
  - pip --version || true
  - python --version || true
  - ls -al . || true
  - pwd || true
  - whoami || true

lint:
  before_script:
    - *debug
    - pip install -r requirements-lint.txt
    - <some more lint specific commands>
  script:
    - echo "lint"

build:
  before_script:
    - *debug
    - pip install -r requirements-build.txt
    - <some more build specific commands>
  script:
    - echo "build"

test:
  before_script:
    - *debug
    - pip install -r requirements-test.txt
    - <some more test specific commands>
  script:
    - echo "test"
```

Every `before_script` and `script` are different in every job. However, every `before_script` begins with the same `debug` anchor call. What I want is to specify globally that I want every `before_script` to include `- *debug` at the start instead of rewriting it for every job.

I could also simply do:

```yaml
default:
  before_script:
    - *debug

...

test:
  script:
    - pip install -r requirements-test.txt
    - <some more test specific commands>
    - echo "test"
```

but it mixes up the commands to setup the tests and the commands to run the tests and I feel that it goes against what `before_script` exists for.

Is it possible to include a command at the start of every `before_script` in `.gitlab-ci.yml`? If yes, how?

---

As expected, doing this:

```yaml
default:
  before_script:
    - *debug

...

test:
  before_script:
    - pip install -r requirements-test.txt
    - <some more test specific commands>
  script:
    - echo "test"
```

does not run the `*debug` command in the `test` job. The `test`'s `before_script` overrides the default one instead of being merged into with it.

Comment: Haven't you already done it with the anchor? Did using an anchor not work? If it didn't work, can you include what happened?

Comment: "Haven't you already done it with the anchor? Did using an anchor not work?" -> It's not using an anchor that fails, it's calling this anchor in every `before_script` that does not work. If I create a default `before_script`, it is replaced in every job by their own `before_script` making the default one useless.

Comment: can you provide the merged YAML for one of the jobs as an example?

Comment: @Arty-chan I provided an additional example of what does not work